# Is conditional template overriding part of the Jekyll framework?

Tags: jekyll

I'm interested in using Jekyll to host a dozen business websites that share a lot of information and web interfaces in common.  Hence, I'm curious if what I'm about to ask is easily supported by Jekyll.

If this were another website platform like WordPress, Magento, etc.. etc... I might set up default templates for my website like this:

```
tpl/default/header.html
tpl/default/footer.html
tpl/default/privacy-policy.html
tpl/default/pricing.html
tpl/default/contact/map.html
tpl/default/contact/form.html
```

Then for each business that signs up with me, I will set up a folder for them called `tpl/<businessname>/`.   Then, the platform will create a website using all the html files in the `tpl/<businessname>/` directory.  Whenever a template does not exist in the `tpl/<businessname>` directory, then the platform will use the corresponding template in the `tpl/default/` directory.

As an example, let's say Bicycle Shop wants a website from me.  I go ahead and create this:

```
tpl/bicycyle-shop/contact/map.html
```

Then in my layout files, I might make calls like this:

```
<?php
define('ORG','bicycle-shop');
put_tmpl('contact/form.html'); // this will use tpl/default/contact/form.html
put_tmpl('contact/map.html'); // this will use tpl/bicycle-shop/contact/map.html

function put_tmpl($tplname) { 
    if(file_exists('tpl/'.ORG.'/'.$tplname))
        include('tpl/'.ORG'.'/'.$tplname);
    else
        include('tpl/default/'.explode('/',$tplname)[count(explode('/',$tplname))-1]);
}
?>
```

I'm curious how a behaviour like this is achieved in Jekyll?

---

ADDITIONAL

One way that just occurred to me was to have a `_config.yml` that has variables like:

```
tmpl:
  home: tpl/default/header.html
  pricing: tpl/default/pricing.html
  ...etc...
```

Then each business has `_config<businessname>.yml` that overrides the appropriate `tmpl` variables.  Would that be the Jekyll convention? Or is there something out of the box with Jekyll that does this better?

Comment: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/

Answer (score 0):

There are themes... you just install a theme as a gem in your config. When you need to override a theme file, you just put that file in your _layouts or _includes directory.

Super simple.